# CSS Grid Layout - Aligning <p> with input fields

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner to HTML and CSS, and am trying to create this responsive calculator website. The problem however, is that the mid-column, where the different calculations symbols are placed do not show up in line with the input fields placed besides them (Please see the picture attached). I am just wondering how to potentially fix this so that the symbols are aligned with the input fields

```css
/*Online Calculator CSS*/

.grid {
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 20px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 100px);
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}


/*Title*/

.title {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 1;
}


/*Sub Header*/

.sub-header {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 2;
}


/*Addition*/

.input-one-add {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.input-two-add {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.addition-sign {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 3;
}


/*Subtraction*/

.input-one-min {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.input-two-min {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.subtraction-sign {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 4;
}


/*Multiplication*/

.input-one-mul {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.input-two-mul {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.multiplication-sign {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 5;
}


/*Division*/

.input-one-div {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.input-two-div {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.division-sign {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 6;
}

.addition-sign,
.subtraction-sign,
.multiplication-sign,
.division-sign {}


/*Styling*/

h1 {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #13c48c;
}

h4 {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #9F9F9F;
}

.num-one,
.num-two {
  border-color: #13c48c;
  border-width: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: bold;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.num-one:focus,
.num-two:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.num-one {}

.num-two {}

.add-sum {}

p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: "Verdana";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Online Calculator Tutorial.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="title">
      <header>
        <h1>Online Calcualator</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
    <!-- Sub Header -->
    <div class="sub-header">
      <h4>Calculations:</h4>
    </div>

    <!-- Addition -->
    <!-- Field #1 -->
    <div class="input-one-add">
      <input id="num-one-add" , class="num-one">
    </div>
    <!-- Addition Sign -->
    <div class="addition-sign">
      <p>+</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Field #2 -->
    <div class="input-two-add">
      <input id="num-two-add" , class="num-two">
    </div>
    <!-- Add Sum -->
    <div class="sum-add">
      <p id="add-sum-add" , class="add-sum"></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Subtraction -->
    <!-- Field #1 -->
    <div class="input-one-min">
      <input id="num-one-minus" , class="num-one">
    </div>
    <!-- Subtraction Sign -->
    <div class="subtraction-sign">
      <p>-</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Field #2 -->
    <div class="input-two-min">
      <input id="num-two-minus" , class="num-two">
    </div>
    <!-- Add Sum -->
    <div class="sum-min">
      <p id="add-sum-min" , class="add-sum"></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Multiplication -->
    <!-- Field #1 -->
    <div class="input-one-mul">
      <input id="num-one-multiplication" , class="num-one">
    </div>
    <!-- Multiplication Sign -->
    <div class="multiplication-sign">
      <p>*</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Field #2 -->
    <div class="input-two-mul">
      <input id="num-two-multiplication" , class="num-two">
    </div>
    <!-- Add Sum -->
    <div class="sum-mul">
      <p id="add-sum-mul" , class="add-sum"></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Division -->
    <!-- Field #1 -->
    <div class="input-one-div">
      <input id="num-one-division" , class="num-one">
    </div>
    <!-- Division Sign -->
    <div class="division-sign">
      <p>/</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Field #2 -->
    <div class="input-two-div">
      <input id="num-two-division" , class="num-two">
    </div>
    <!-- Add Sum -->
    <div class="sum-div">
      <p id="add-sum-div" , class="add-sum"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you starting your columns from 2 instead of 1? Are you trying to align it to the center or something?

Comment: yes, is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph elements (`<p></p>`) typically have a margin above and below. (Inspect your example in Chrome; you'll see that margin, and that it comes from the user agent style sheet.) If you insist on keeping the symbols as paragraphs, you need to unset that margin.

A rule like

```
.grid p { margin: 0; }
```

would do it.

I'd argue, though, that you'd do better to get rid of the `<p>`s and `</p>`s altogether. They add nothing semantically, as those symbols definitely aren't paragraphs.